# Subscribing to an API call: Angular2

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular application which allows users to comment on a particular media file (like video). When a comment is posted, it makes a http POST call which stores the comment in the database.

While loading the component, ngOnInit loads all the comments from the database by making a http GET call. But, the comments doesn't get updated without refreshing the page when a new comment is posted. Is their a way to update the comments list without refreshing the page when a comment is posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity let's say you have one component `ViewComponent`, that shows the list of comments as well as the comment form to add a new comment. The `ViewComponent` has a local state of the comments like `public comments: Comment[]`, which gets initialized by the GET api call in your `ngOnInit()`.

I'm assuming you have a service like `CommentsService` that makes the api calls.
When you add a comment, the function `addComment(comment)` is called, which handles the POST request. When the POST was successful, the comment is added to your comments array.

If the service returns an Observable (here without unsubscribe):

```
addComment(comment: Comment): void {
  this.commentService.add(comment)
    .subscribe(comment => {
      this.comments.push(comment);
    });
}
```

If the service returns a Promise:

```
addComment(comment: Comment): void {
  this.commentService.add(comment)
    .then(comment => {
      this.comments.push(comment);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`subscribe` your `http.post` and when `success` posting add the post to your array of posts `this.posts.push(newPost)`